# How to connect two database of different wordpress sites?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, authentication

I am having two different sites based on wordpress. I want to give access to the users to both the sites even if they sign-up on any of one.

Example:

If user xyz sign-up for example1.com then user's data must be stored in both website's data-base example1.com and example2.com so user don't need to sign-up for example2.com if he has sign-up in example1.com and vice-versa.

So how can I connect this data-base with each other?

If user sign-up in example1.com then fields of data-base in wordpress having table wp_user by default should receive that information of user in both sites.

In short, I want to connect data-base of both sites having table wp_user.

Comment: If it's shared hosting then pray that your provider offers remote sql

Comment: While not that familiar with WP myself, Im sure you can create a plugin that hooks the create user and update user events and just add what you need there to connect to the additional DB.

Comment: what you want is "single sign-on": https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/sso

Comment: @Marc I want that if user sign-up in example1.com then fields of data-base in wordpress having table wp_user by default should receive that information of user in both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one common database for all your sites and connect it with individual sites so that it can stored information and can be used with any sites you want.

Comment: Any other ways actually I am not knowing more about mysql.

Answer (score 0):

There are many SSO solutions available for Wordpress, including your scenario.

Checkout: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/single-sign-on
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/sso

Try this plugin: https://github.com/voceconnect/wp-multisite-sso

Comment: what if I didn't want to use plugins because I had already used lots of plugins and want to do this without plugin